# How to display total number of post done by user, it should display at authors page wordpress

Tags: users

I have added the below function to user.php but it cant display the count on the authors page.

function count_user_posts( $userid, $post_type = 'post', $public_only = false ) {
global $wpdb;

```
$where = get_posts_by_author_sql( $post_type, true, $userid, $public_only );

$count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->posts $where" );

/**
 * Filters the number of posts a user has written.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 * @since 4.1.0 Added `$post_type` argument.
 * @since 4.3.1 Added `$public_only` argument.
 *
 * @param int          $count       The user's post count.
 * @param int          $userid      User ID.
 * @param string|array $post_type   Single post type or array of post types to count the number of posts for.
 * @param bool         $public_only Whether to limit counted posts to public posts.
 */
return apply_filters( 'get_usernumposts', $count, $userid, $post_type, $public_only );
```

}

Comment: `user.php`? DO NOT EVER EDIT CORE FILES. There are some simple functions available to display number of posts by an author. In your case, a simple solution would be [`count_user_posts(get_queried_object_id())`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/count_user_posts/) in your theme's `author.php` file.